# How to extract digit from string in SQL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a string which has at least one digit per bracket. Now, I want to extract the digit(s). How do I do this in Redshift sql?

```
    ColumnA     ColumnB (output)
    (,,,3,)     3
    (2,,,)      2
    (,,,1)      1
    (1,,,3)     13
```

Comment: regex `(\d+)` will work.

Comment: For that 4th example, what's the intended value to extract? You've got two digits in the bracket.

Comment: @JakobLovern just added that use case.

Comment: @JakobLovern you have to escape the parens `\(\d+\)`

Comment: @titutubs you say one digit per bracket, but your last row has two digits.

Comment: @sleepystar96 i corrected the typo. thanks for calling it out.

Comment: If you search and replace on  `[^\d]`=>(empty) then it'll delete everything that's not a digit. See https://regex101.com/r/zIRBtS/1

Comment: Can someone paste an official solution with the columns as context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html). Here's a snippet:

```sql
CREATE TABLE x (col1 varchar(255))

INSERT INTO x VALUES ('(,,,3,)'),('(2,,,)'),('(,,,1)'),('(1,,,3)');
select col1, 
       regexp_replace(col1,'[^\d]','','g') as col2
from x;
```

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| (,,,3,) | 3 |
| (2,,,) | 2 |
| (,,,1) | 1 |
| (1,,,3) | 13 |

Try it in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/433f2/6)

Comment: @Jajob Lovern what is the 'g' for? I am getting an error

Comment: The 'g' is a regex flag indicating to replace all matches.

Answer (score 2):

Jakob's answer would work. You can also do the same thing with REPLACE:

```
CREATE TABLE x (col1 varchar(255)) 
INSERT INTO x VALUES ('(,,,3,)'),('(2,,,)'),('(,,,1)'),('(1,,,3)')

SELECT REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
          col1, ',', ''
        ) ,')', ''
    ), '(', ''
) FROM x
```

| replace |
| --- |
| 3 |
| 2 |
| 1 |
| 13 |

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/433f2/8)

Comment: This answer is probably more portable tbh. I've had spotty reception with REGEXP_REPLACE across databases, while REPLACE is part of the ansi spec.